# sugarCRM Community Edition: How to make a field required?

Tags: php, field, sugarcrm, required

I have been googling this for a while now, and nothing is coming up.  I am totally new to CRM and PHP, and I know practically nothing about either, but this task was dropped on my lap last week.

All I want to do is make the account name field required when creating a contact.  I can't figure out why the account name field shows up on the create contact page, but not in the fields section in studio after clicking contacts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I am sorry if this was worded in any confusing way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contacts -> Account Name is not technically a field, it's a relationship that exists between the Accounts and Contacts module. That is why Studio doesn't show "Account Name" in the fields section, which is normally the easiest way of making a field required.

However, relationships are just fancy vardefs, and you can still use a minor code tweak to make this a required field. Create a file in `/custom/Extensions/modules/Contacts/Ext/Vardefs/` and name it something relevant, e.g. "account_name.php" and populate it with the following:

```
<?php
$dictionary['Contact']['fields']['account_name']['required'] = true;
```

Be sure to save this with appropriate permissions, then run a Repair and Rebuild.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm sorry I didn't come back sooner.  I figured it out shortly after but I haven't been here long enough to answer my own question.  I appreciate this!